# How can I extract every instance of a single word that occurs in multiple .wav files?

Tags: praat

I have the .wav and corresponding .TextGrid files in one directory. What's a quick way to extract/slice sound file intervals labeled with the Chinese character in question?
I'd then want to store every utterance of that one character into a separate directory.

I've tried using this script from UCLA, but it doesn't output anything into the directory I specify.
http://phonetics.linguistics.ucla.edu/facilities/acoustic/Segmenter.txt

Comment: Do you mean "in one shot, only using Praat scripting", or can you run a separate external program to do some of the work?

Comment: In one shot, using a Praat script.

Comment: As this is really a programming question I think it should be asked at stackoverflow.com

Comment: Already done! However, response time seems slow despite the number of people viewing it...

Comment: did you get an answer? basic steps in the Praat script would be to 1. read in wav and corresponding textured, 2. write a for loop to loop through all the intervals on the tier containing the Chinese character, matching that certain character, 3. extract the sound and textgrid (if applicable) and write to file.